# Why is socat not working here? (4in6 for UDP traffic)

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, socat

I have a TS3 server running on IPv6 only. I wanted to use a dualstack VPS as a 4in6 tunnel, but UDP traffic gets lost with this configuration:

```
socat UDP4-LISTEN:9987,fork UDP6:server@example.net:9987
```

TCP traffic works fine:

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:22,fork TCP6:server@example.net:22
```

Comment: What's the MTU on the 4in6 interfaces? Try reducing it to 1240. If that doesn't help then you'll need to run packet captures on virtual and physical interfaces at both ends of the tunnel to see where the packets get lost.

Comment: This was a firewall issue not a socat issue at all.